# YTPlayerView inside a UICollectionView Dynamic Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-api, uicollectionview

**Update 1:**
here is the code for `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MBDynamicCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:
                                  indexPath];
    video= videoData[indexPath.row];

    if(!cell) {
        cell = [MBDynamicCollectionViewCell new];
    }

    [cell.videoPlayer loadWithVideoId:video.videoID];

    cell.label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",video.videoTitle];

    return cell;
}
```

and here is how I sent the request to server

```
NSURL *url=[ NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=AIzaSyClU73k2yYl7gufFDxHU7uhGSCuM78f7Aw&channelId=UCW9CKYMhpJM-B1B0PGBB9Ew&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=20"];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSOperationQueue *queue= [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,NSData *data,NSError *error){
    if(error){
        NSLog(@"error:%@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
    else{



        NSError *error;
        NSMutableDictionary *allVideos= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
        // NSString *string=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        // NSLog(@"%@",string);
        for(NSDictionary *dictionary in allVideos[@"items"]){

            NSDictionary *videoID=dictionary[@"id"];
           // NSLog(@"video id is %@", videoID[@"videoId"]);
            NSDictionary *snippet= dictionary[@"snippet"];
            //NSLog(@"video title is %@", snippet[@"title"]);
            NSDictionary *thumbnails= dictionary[@"snippet"][@"thumbnails"][@"default"];
            //NSLog(@"video image url is %@",thumbnails[@"url"]);

            video=[[MBVideoClass alloc] initWithID:videoID[@"videoId"] withTitle:snippet[@"title"] withImg:thumbnails[@"url"] delegate:self];

            [videoData addObject:video];
        }
        videoData= [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[videoData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred]];
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
    }

}];
```

**Orignal Question**

I have added `YTPlayerView` inside a `UICollectionView` Dynamic cell.
My app crashes with error on "bad access on create new web view"
This problem arises when I try to initialise the webView inside `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`.
Any idea?

```
1   0x7133239 StartWebThread()
2   0x37579b7 __pthread_once_handler
3   0x37695eb _os_once
4   0x3757966 pthread_once
5   0x7132fce WebThreadEnable
6   0x610181a +[WebView(WebPrivate) enableWebThread]
7   0x60fbcb0 WebKitInitialize
8   0x85b8f0 ___UIApplicationLoadWebKit_block_invoke
9   0x34109cd _dispatch_client_callout
10  0x33fa26d dispatch_once_f
11  0x33fa1cb dispatch_once
12  0x85b7f8 _UIApplicationLoadWebKit
13  0x21d9f59 _class_initialize
14  0x21df981 lookUpImpOrForward
15  0x21df8e1 _class_lookupMethodAndLoadCache3
16  0x21ea547 objc_msgSend
17  0x33161 -[MBVideoListCollectionViewController collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:]
18  0x11e45ee -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:isFocused:]
19  0x11e42ff -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:]
20  0x11e8761 -[UICollectionView _updateVisibleCellsNow:]
21  0x11ed7df -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews]
22  0x92b3d4 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]
23  0x21ed059 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:]
24  0x5c5b096 -[CALayer layoutSublayers]
25  0x5c4e8b6 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
26  0x5c4e71a CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
27  0x5c40ee7 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*)
28  0x5c75847 CA::Transaction::commit()
29  0x5c75bef CA::Transaction::release_thread(void*)
30  0x375929d _pthread_tsd_cleanup
31  0x3758e22 _pthread_exit
```

Comment: can you post some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While updating the question I realized what i was doing wrong.
Problem was that I was reloading the collectionView from background thread.
Therefore following line fixed the crash

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
});
```

Hope this helps anyone else.

Comment: this is not working for me
the app crashes on iPhone 6, 6s and all simulators.